# How to make Google+ circle renaming reflect on Android app

Tags: google-plus

I renamed a G+ circle, but it hasn't reflected in the Android app. I hit refresh many times, changed views between circles, went into notifications etc, but the name is still the old one. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is better suited for [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) than here, but here's some things to try.

You probably just need to wait for things to sync. (In fact, I'd be willing to bet money that the issue will be resolved before you come back to read this answer.)

1. Under `Settings | Accounts | Google | (your account)` make sure `Google+` is checked. If it is, try unchecking it then checking it again. This should force a sync.
2. If the above doesn't work, try [the standard measures to deal with a truculent Android app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13347/267). That is, try the following, in order, and stop when the issue is fixed:

   From `Settings | Apps | Google+`

   - Force stop
   - Clear cache
   - Clear data
   - Restart the phone
   - Uninstall and re-install (the nuclear option)

Comment: I logged out and back in and it worked. Tt was a sync issue I guess.